# assign value to variable and pass it to command line in Bat file

Tags: batch-file

I want to declare a variable in a bat file and pass this variable to the command line. 
My bat file:

```
@echo off

SET dbname="gss_annot"
cd "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\webclient\db\nucleotide"
call "C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe" "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\webclient\db\nucleotide\update_blastdb.pl" --passive --decompress %dbname%> C:\perl_out.log 2>&1
```

I want to pass `dbname` variable to the call statement. How should it look like?

Answer (score 0):

I solve it.
Just remove `""` from text and delete the white space between thae variable and the value.

```
dbname=gss_annot
```

Thanks,

Comment: the securest syntax to set a variable is `set "var=value"` (note the position of the quotes; they are not part of the variable but make the `set` command save against poisonous characters like `|`, `&` and others)